# Which 1,2-methylene shift is more favourable in ring expansions where ring has substituents

Tags: organic-chemistry, alcohols, carbocation, elimination

[image]

In the above reaction, first the -OH group is protonated after which it leaves creating a carbocation intermediate as shown[image]

Now, ring expansion is a more favourable rearrangement, however there is a confusion between which methylene shift should take place (the two possibilities are shown in orange and yellow) each of which would give two different products - 
3-methyl cyclohexene or 2-methyl cyclohexene.

Please explain which methylene shift should occur and why?